# Removing data from a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to prune some data from my data frame but only the rows where there are duplicates in the "To country" column

My data frame looks like this:

```
   Year From country To country  Points
0  2016      Albania    Armenia       0
1  2016      Albania    Armenia       2
2  2016      Albania  Australia      12
      Year    From country       To country  Points
2129  2016  United Kingdom  The Netherlands       0
2130  2016  United Kingdom          Ukraine      10
2131  2016  United Kingdom          Ukraine       5

[2132 rows x 4 columns]
```

I try this on it:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='To country', inplace=True)
```

And what happens is this:

```
   Year From country To country  Points
0  2016      Albania    Armenia       0
2  2016      Albania  Australia      12
4  2016      Albania    Austria       0
    Year From country       To country  Points
46  2016      Albania  The Netherlands       0
48  2016      Albania          Ukraine       0
50  2016      Albania   United Kingdom       5

[50 rows x 4 columns]
```

While this does get rid of the duplicated 'To country' entries, it also removes all the values of the 'From country' column. I must be using the drop_duplicates() wrong, but the pandas documentation isn't helping me understand why its dropping more than I'd expect it to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this behavior is correct—assuming every team played every other team, it's finding the firsts, and all of those firsts are "From" Albania.

From what you've said below, you want to keep row 0, but not row 1 because it repeats **both** the `To` and `From` countries. The way to eliminate those is:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['To country', 'From country'], inplace=True)
```

Comment: Oh. I understand now, what it's doing, but I don't know how to make it do what I want. What I would like is to remove the duplicates for each country; ie:
   Year From country To country  Points
0  2016      Albania    Armenia       0
2  2016      Albania  Australia      12
      Year    From country       To country  Points
2129  2016  United Kingdom  The Netherlands       0
2130  2016  United Kingdom          Ukraine      10


Something like that, I hope thats readable in a comment

Comment: Duplicates for each *pair* of countries? For instance, `(Albania, Armenia)` happening only once? Or duplicates between the columns? As in, you don't want Armenia as both `To` and `From`?

Comment: Yes like that, I'd still like to have the from country column to have all the countries, but just getting rid of only the duplicated values in the 'To countries' column assosicated to the From countries column

Comment: Yes, thank you. That works perfectly. My only question: why does it work? is it saying to look for duplicates in the to country with respect to the from country column?

Comment: It looks for duplicated pairs. To be considered a duplicate, all columns in `subset` must match.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to group by the 'to country' name and take the first (or the last, if you prefer) row from each group:

```
df.groupby('To country').first().reset_index()
#        To country  Year    From country  Points
#0          Armenia  2016         Albania       0
#1        Australia  2016         Albania      12
#2  The Netherlands  2016  United Kingdom       0
#3          Ukraine  2016  United Kingdom      10
```

Compared to aryamccarthy's solution, this one gives you more control over which duplicates to keep.

Comment: Though I feel the intent is less clear, I think this is a creative use of the tools. Indeed, it does give more control if needed.